# Nosql and SQL Server in 2012 and 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, nosql

I have heard that SQL Server 2014 is going to have some features that you would expect to find in a NoSQL database.

What features of NoSQL databases will SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2012 have if any?

Comment: I think you've heard wrong - neither SQL Server 2012 nor 2014 really have any "NoSQL" features that I'm aware of...

Comment: SQL Server 2014 added in-memory OLTP Engine aka Hekaton which Microsoft claims make database operations much faster.  You could argue that this gives SQL Server NoSQL like speeds while keeping the capabilities of a relational database.